# How to write multiple index values instead of just one

Tags: javascript, html

My function needs to call a number of index values based on the users input (1-5) based on job duties they want to see and then call from the array the index values, so if the user inputs 3, index values 0,1,2 need to be written. Currently it only writes the one associated with the input not all below that input. This is what I have so far:

```
function jobduties() {
    var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var y = x-1;
    var duties = ["Sales", "Customer Service", "Management", "Driving", "Cleaning"];
    var z = " ";

    while(x > y){
       z += z + duties[y];
       y++;
       document.getElementById("print").innerHTML= z;
   }
}
```

Comment: How about `var y = 1` ?

Comment: y = 1 didn't work, I'll try the other code

Comment: Note: `z += z + duties[y];` will cause duplications

Comment: Also, in your code, your duties will run into each other with no spaces between them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting `y = x-1`, so if the user enters 3 (x=3), y will be 2 (x-1)... In your while you start with y = 2, you add that to z, and then increase y, so you are only evaluating y = 2, since the next one is y=3, and that doesn't satisfy your condition (x > y)

Try these changes...
change `var y = x - 1;`
for `var y = 0;`

And also remove the + where you edit the z variable.

Edit: By the way, I just answer following the method you choosed, but I strongly recommend you to use a FOR loop instead, much easier..

Comment: you mean change `+=` to `+` or remove the `z +` to the right of `+=` ... note, neither of these will change the fact that the text for the duties will have no spaces

Comment: Yes i agree, but this is for an assignment I have where i have to use a while loop, thank you though

Comment: Finally worked, any idea how to format it, so it doesn't come out all as one long piece of text?

Comment: firstly, `var z = '';` no space at the beginning, and then `z += duties[y] + ' ';`

Comment: Change the entire z line inside the while for this one: "z = duties[y] + "<br>;" if you want the jobs to be rendered in different lines